# Any way to globally define Jenkins User-defined Axis

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to globally define a variable name and set of values to use as an axis in Multi-configuration projects? I was thinking it'd be handy to have a check-box for each value.

My use case is various projects that I want to build w/ tool-chains (C/C++ world, not Java). At the moment I'm doing this w/ a variable that identifies the tool-chain used to initialize the build environment. I'm looking for a common way to have a set of choices across projects.

I'm a Jenkins newbie, so could be going about this all wrong...

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to script your Jenkins job definitions with the [Job-DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin)

This way not only can you define the axes centrally but you can script the whole config in Groovy. So if your needs change or you learn better ways to do things you only have to update in one place and regenerate the lot.

e.g.

```
matrixJob('example') {
    axes {
        label('label', 'linux', 'windows')
        jdk('jdk6', 'jdk7')
        configure { axes ->
            axes << 'org.acme.FooAxis'()
        }
    } }
```

References

- job-dsl [sand pit](http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/)
- [method reference](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.MatrixJob.axes)